# Webform and fabric.js integration

Tags: 7, javascript, webforms

I'm trying to design a form that allows a user to design a custom tshirt. I was thinking of using the fabric.js library to let the user design a custom image and submit it with other custom information filled out in the webform module.

Is there an approach anyone can suggest that would let me take the image designed in the javascript and submit it along with the webform info? I'm pretty sure I can figure out fabric.js by itself but integrating with Drupal might be too advanced? I don't know if it is even possible. Still at a beginner level here with javascript and php.

Comment: Drupal 7 or 8??

Comment: Ah sorry Drupal 7!

Comment: Hi @Paul, it's sufficient to put the Drupal core version in the tags. That's "7" for Drupal 7 and "8" for Drupal 8.